# Unknown database error importing dumpfile with backticks

Tags: mysql, import

I have a problem with importing a MySQL 4 Dumpfile into another MySQL 4 database.

Here a piece of the dumpfile:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `light_interface` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `light_interface`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Aktullestimmung`;
CREATE TABLE `Aktullestimmung` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `brightness` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
```

The problem is this:

```
USE `light_interface`;
```

The error:

```
Unknown database '`light_interface`'
```

Note single quote, apostrophe

I got the error "unknown Database", but when I delete the apostrophe so the Statement is:

```
USE light_interface;
```

Then the complete import works fine.

I think MySQL tries to use a database `light_interface` instead of `light_interface`, but why?

On another installation it works, the OS is a Suse Linux 9.2